# How to fire different MessageType with Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

it's not clear to me how to fire messages different than "Message" with Bot Framework using c#:

http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-types/

For example I wish to send EndOfConversation message. I used to call

`context.Done<string>(message);`

but nothing seems to happen as

```
private Message HandleSystemMessage(Message message)
{         
     else if (message.Type == "UserAddedToConversation")
     {

     }
}
```

is not fired and state variables are not resetted.

How to fire this kind of events?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that `EndOfConversation` message is triggered by Bot Connector, for example in the case when user has closed the chat connection with the bot. `context.Done` is used by the Dialog to indicate that the actual dialog has finished and we can access the result of the dialog, and it does not necessarily mean that the conversation with the user is over (for example, you may want to start another dialog in the same conversation).

Comment: Hi Dmitri,

I use context.Done and the event is not triggered. If I use emulator the event is triggered. That's strange

Comment: @Jano, I think it is the correct behavior. When you call context.Done, it just finishes the dialog with the user, but the conversation can theoretically go on - that is why EndOfConversation is not triggered. EndOfConversation is triggered on the user side (Emulator, actual chat client, etc.), and not on the side of the chat bot.